# Can we use multiple yaml files in a single spring boot application?

Tags: java, spring-boot

I have one yaml file that reads all the environment profiles. I need another yaml file to create a feature switch that i can turn on/off during deployment. And how can we define the feature switch in properties file.

Comment: I can get the value from one yaml file but not from the other yaml file.

Comment: 1) A yaml file can't "read" anything. It's a file with properties, not code. 2) You mention "profiles", and profiles are the way to include multiple configurations, to be chosen at load time. Read documentation on [how profiles work](https://docs.spring.io/spring/docs/current/spring-framework-reference/html/beans.html#beans-environment), and how you can have [profile-specific configuration files](https://docs.spring.io/spring-boot/docs/current/reference/html/boot-features-external-config.html).

Answer (score 13):

Yes, you can use multiple YAML files if you use **spring profile**. For example, if you start your JVM with the following flag:

`-Dspring.profiles.active=deployed,cassandra`

It will pick up the following application YAML files:

`application.yml`, `application-deployed.yml`, and `application-cassandra.yml`

Answer (score 4):

Another way to do this, is by adding this key in the application.yml file like below

```
spring:
  profiles:
    include:
      - student
      - address
```

and you can name your yaml files, as

```
application-student.yml, application-address.yml
```